# Calling variables in the same class with python

Tags: python, class, variables

I am trying to call a variable defined in a function, inside another function of the same class, but with `self` doesn't work.

```
class Project():
    def function1(self):
        a='hello world,'

    def function2(self):
        b=self.a + ' I am alive'

Project1=Project()
print Project1.function1()
print Project1.function2()
```

python says: `Project instance has no attribute 'a'`.

I don't know very well how to use classes. I didn't use `__init__` 'cause I do not have anything to put, is there maybe a way to add it even if I do not need it formally?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: in `function1`, `a` is local. You probably wanted `self.a='hello world, '`

Comment: so, if I want to have the printing of function2, I should define a in function1 as self.a?

Comment: Yes. In your code as it is, `self.a` (attribute `a` of the object `self`) is never defined. `a` in `function1` is local variable. See [Classes - Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).

Comment: Thanks to everyone ;) now, it finally works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `a` and `b` variables are local. You can only use these variables in the method scope. If you want a class attribute (shared with all the class) you have to set the like `self.a = ...` and `self.b = ...`.
In python is not necessary create a constructor method `__init__` neither initialize these attributes.
But in your example if you call `functions2` before `function1` it will crash because you are using one attribute that doen't exist. Then is recommended initialize the attributes.
You can initialize the attributes like this:

```
class Project:
    a = ''
    b = ''

    def function1(self):
        self.a='hello world,'

    def function2(self):
        self.b=self.a + ' I am alive'
```

**More things to keep in mind:**
1. The variables are in lower case and snake case: `project1 = Project()`
2. Your prints won't print anything because your functions don't return anything. You have to return something like:

```
def function1():
    return 'hello world,'
```

or if you need to set a and print:

```
def function1():
    self.a = 'hello world,'
    return self.a
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need is:

```
    def function1(self):
      self.a = 'hello world, '
```

Within `function1`, `a` is a local variable as someone stated, whereas `self.a` is an attribute attached to your current object.

Comment: and do I need to use __init__, or is not compulsory in a class?

Comment: It works the way it is. You only need `__init__` if you want to set `self.a` right after the object is created (instantiated).

Answer (score 0):

In `function1(self)` you need to change `a=` to `self.a=`. In your original code you were creating a local variable `a`, you need to explicitly use `self` to attach the variable `a` to the instance of the object and stay persistent across function calls.